# Clear content of whole page for just one route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I build an ember application with following concept.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>
```

So, in every route, outlet will be placed by template's html. But now I have got a request to create one more route which have completely different content to show and even need to clear `<h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>` from above. I doubt if i can acheive this directly. But can i do some tweaks to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Hay u need to make nested route . 
Such as

> this.resource('products');

```
this.resource('product', { path: '/products/:title' } );
```

Lets say on **products** template you must {[outlet}} **product** template.
This gives you possibility to manipulate hbs.ses differently. Let's say a list next to products that comes from product template.

```
> 
>script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='product' >

      {{title}}
    <p>{{description}}</p>
 <p>Buy for ${{price}}</p> </script>



<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='products'>
{{#each}}
{{#link-to 'product' this classNames='list-group-item'}}
{{title}}
{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}   
{{outlet}}
</script>
```

Comment: i know about nested routes. But for this, i have to edit code in all places. I am just looking for a work around where this doesnt happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("header", function(){
        this.resource("normalroute1");
        this.resource("normalroute2");
        ...
    });
    this.resource("specialroute");
});


<script data-template-name='header' type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Structure your project like that and use the "specialroute" for the case where you do not want the header to appear.